# Machine keeps backups of files that I have already deleted

Tags: files, filesystems, vim

I recently found out that my machine keeps backups of files that I have already deleted.

For example, a file called `a.svg` that I have deleted in the past, still exists in the directory it was deleted from but with a new filename called `a.svg~`. Again, another deleted file called `README.txt` still exists with a filename `README.txt~` and so on.

Moreover, you can not see directly these kind of files but only when you check "show hidden and backup files" in Nautilus or when you `ls` in a terminal.

How can I disable those backup files and have my files deleted for good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not deleted files. These are backup files used by the editors that last changed them. For example `vim` creates a backup file of the previous state before you save changes.

If these files annoy you, there's usually a way to turn off this behavior. For example in case of `vim`, you could put `set nobackup` in your `~/.vimrc` file. Look for similar options in your editor.

As [@Kiwy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53092/kiwy) remarked in comments:

> Be also aware that those file can be consider as a security risk when it comes to web server as some bot on internet look for file like `*.php~` to get the content of your php source file and read it to find security leaks.

So yes, I too recommend to disable this kind of backup mechanism.

Comment: Be also aware that those file can be consider as a security risk when it comes to web server as some bot on internet look for file like `*.php~` to get the content of your `php` source file and read it to find security leaks.

Answer (score 2):

`vim` automatically saves such backup files.  This can be changed in your `.vimrc` with the following lines:

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
```

Other text editors may exhibit similar behavior and will have similar options.

Your question is misleadingly phrased - Deleted files are being deleted, you are just not also deleting the backups your text editor is making for you.  Exposing these files is an option in whatever file manager you are using.

I assure you, `ls` has no built-in default suppression of files ending in a tilde.